# How to properly use jQuery "context"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I use the context argument of jQuery to specify where I'd like the selection to take place. For example, I thought I could do something like.

```
var boxes = $("#div").find("input[type='checkbox']");
var selected = $(":checked", boxes);
```

However, apparently I totally misunderstand this feature. How can I use it.

Also, I know I could just put the `:checked` in the initial selection; I'm just trying to understand this context selector.

Thanks

Comment: @Blazemonger Can you show me an example of what you mean? How would context apply to children? Maybe it's just me, but "context" seems like it should apply to the larger...er, context..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var selected = $(":checked", boxes);
```

is equivalent to

```
var selected = boxes.find(":checked");
```

while what you want is

```
var selected = boxes.filter(":checked");
```

Here, the context parameter isn't really useful to you as you want to look among your boxes, not among the descendants of the boxes.

See [filter documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Thanks dystroy. Can you show me an example of where the context selector __would__ be useful?

Comment: Any time you use `find`. For example your first line could have been `$("input[type='checkbox']", $("#div"));` which might make more sense if instead of `$("#div"));` you reuse an already declared jQuery object.

Comment: What is the advantage? Is it faster? Do you find it easier to read?

Comment: It's a little faster when the second argument isn't a jQuery object but a raw DOM object. But that's not significant. It might be, sometimes, a little clearer. But that doesn't matter much in any case.

Comment: So basically useless..?